# Checking error in my code for validate letters numbers and whitespace in php

Tags: php, regex, string, validation, pattern-matching

I made a form for submit name of the product website in php. I wrote simple code that matches only letters, numbers and whitespace but no special characters. Its working fine for me.

I tried this

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/",$name))
```

Could you please found any error or any principle of writing the correct expression that i forgot here in my code .?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. I read your question 10 times and I am not grasping it. Are you asking that you want to also check for special characters on top of the letters, numbers and whitespace?

Comment: @Fred-ii- As I understand it he/she just wants someone to peer review the regex to see if it is correct.

Comment: @Ivar They should have tested it before posting then.

Comment: Looks ok, but consider this.  Is a tab a white space for your requirements?  Look up this page http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php   Whitespace in that page includes more than just a "regular space".  Depends what you need.  Like you may want to consider \w for words.

Comment: @Nic Tab and white space required after the first letter or number. Products name could be anything like "Prevnar 13", Bentonite 20" so its necessary to use a space here with alphanumeric. I just want to know whether this code fine or Is there any better way to validate these kind of strings .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, you mention that is must match a space *after* the first leter or number  So you should modify your preg_match like so:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 \t]*$/",$name)
```

This will match the fist letter or number, *then* any number of letters, numbers, space and tab.

Comment: Thanks it works .. for validation i used trim, htmlspecialchars, and stripslashes.